# Access SQL statements filling column with values from another table

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have 2 tables:
Table called "Join_of_LIN_and_LI2" having 2 columns as follows:

```
Fcode   |   Description
103     |
4301    |
5200    |
```

and the second table called "Diam"having 2 columns as follows:

```
Fcode   |   Description
5200    |   S Force Line
```

I want to fill the field "Description" of the table "Join_of_LIN_and_LI2" with the values of the field "Description" of the table "Diam"
when the field "Fcode" of table "Join_of_LIN_and_LI2" is equal to the field "Fcode" of table "Diam".

What SQL statement I should use?
I tried the below but doesn't work

```
UPDATE Join_of_LIN_and_LI2
SET Description = (SELECT Diam.Description
                   FROM Join_of_LIN_and_LI2
                   LEFT JOIN Diam ON Join_of_LIN_and_LI2.Fcode = Diam.Fcode;)
```

It gives an error "Operation must use an updateable query" although I am sure that the user has the permissions to write on that file.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to use a subquery for this. You can just use a join in the `UPDATE` query:

```
UPDATE Join_of_LIN_and_LI2 
    INNER JOIN Diam 
    ON Join_of_LIN_and_LI2.Fcode = Diam.Fcode
SET Join_of_LIN_and_LI2.Description = Diam.Description;
```

The *Operation must use an updateable query* refers to the fact that the query is not updateable. That can happen for many reasons, but in this case, it's because you're using a subquery.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a subquery, but it should be a *correlated* subquery:

```
UPDATE Join_of_LIN_and_LI2
    SET Description = (SELECT Diam.Description
                       FROM Diam 
                       WHERE Join_of_LIN_and_LI2.Fcode = Diam.Fcode
                      );
```

Note:  This is different from the `JOIN` in two ways.  First, this will set `Description` to `NULL` when there are no matches.  The `JOIN` version will not change the existing value.  Second, if there are multiple matches in `Diam`, then this returns a "subquery returns more than one row" type of error.

Comment: This works on older SQL Server versions too.